# Symbol for definition :=

Tags: symbols, math-operators

Sometimes the symbol `:=` is used to denote a definition. For example, `X:=Y+Z` means that `X` is defined to be `Y+Z`.

When using LaTeX, can I just use $:=$, or do I need to do something special?

Comment: Do you also know how to add the equal sign with a 'def' above it?

Comment: @Anatoly, try `\newcommand{\defeq}{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=\joinrel=}}`, so `$x\defeq 2$` should do what you want.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Many do, but then the colon isn't correctly centered. Better to use the package `mathtools` and `\coloneq`. See the [`mathtools` documentation](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) for more information.

---

*Note: In Summer 2022, this macro was changed to **`\coloneq`** (the older `\coloneqq` is still supported as legacy duplicate name).*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately, with `$:=$`, the colon is not centred on the math axis. A solution comes from the `mathtools` package, which defines  `\vcentcolon`  and  `\coloneqq` commands; these lead  to two different results, as regards the horizontal spacing between the colon and the equality sign. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Let  $ a:  = b $

Let  $ a \vcentcolon  = b $

Let  $ a \coloneqq  b $

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\coloneq`(one q!) symbol exists in `mathabx`, `Mnsymbol` and `fdsymbol` (at least). It's named `\coloneqq`in `kpfonts` and `mdsymbol`.

Comment: thanks for this -- What is the use of \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} here?

Comment: Note, as of Summer 2022, the names for this symbol is now called `\coloneq` (one q) in mathtools too. With note "As is listed in the manual for newtxmath/newpxmath" in the mathtools docs

Answer (score -8):

It is not necessary to do anything, `LaTeX` does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here
\[X:=Y+Z
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it does, but incorrectly; in most fonts, the colon is not vertically centred (it sits on the baseline, like a regular `.` does). This is of course wrong since the `=` is vertically centred and this assymetry is seriously ugly.